# PythonのMarkdownモジュールで行頭のスペースが削除されるのを防ぐ方法

Tags: python, markdown

こんにちは。
PythonのmarkdownモジュールでMarkdownをHTMLに変換しようとしています。
しかし、変換を実行すると、下記の実行結果のように行頭のスペースが削除されてしまい、困っています。
何かよい方法はないでしょうか。
もしくは代替えとなりそうなモジュールがあれば、教えていただけますと幸いです。
環境は、Windows10 64ビット、Python 3.7です。

### 変換用のソースコード

```
import markdown, sys
from markdown.extensions.toc import TocExtension
from os import path

if len(sys.argv) != 2:
    print("変換するファイルを指定してください。")
    sys.exit()

input_file = sys.argv[1]
if not path.exists(input_file) or not path.isfile(input_file):
    print("指定されたファイルが見つかりません。")
    sys.exit()

with open(input_file, "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    data = f.read()

md = markdown.Markdown(extensions=['extra', TocExtension(toc_depth="2-6"), 'tables'])
print(md.convert(data))
```

### 実行方法

```
convert.py input.md>output.html
```

### 変換元のMarkdown

```
# テストページ

## 目次

[TOC]

## 見出し1

　これは、テストページです。

## 見出し2

　これは、テストページです。
```

### 実行結果

```
<h1>テストページ</h1>
<h2 id="_1">目次</h2>
<div class="toc">
<ul>
<li><a href="#title">title: テストページ</a></li>
<li><a href="#_1">目次</a></li>
<li><a href="#1">見出し1</a></li>
<li><a href="#2">見出し2</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<h2 id="1">見出し1</h2>
<p>これは、テストページです。</p>
<h2 id="2">見出し2</h2>
<p>これは、テストページです。</p>
```

---

以上、よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

行頭のスペースが削除されてしまうのは、[markdown/blockprocessors.py](https://github.com/Python-Markdown/markdown/blob/master/markdown/blockprocessors.py#L592) で `lstrip()` を実行しているためです。

```
class ParagraphProcessor(BlockProcessor):
    """ Process Paragraph blocks. """
               :
    def run(self, parent, blocks):
               :

            # Create a regular paragraph
            p = etree.SubElement(parent, 'p')
            p.text = block.lstrip()
```

markdown module では以下の様に HTML タグ別に parser を登録しています。

[markdown/blockprocessors.py](https://github.com/Python-Markdown/markdown/blob/master/markdown/blockprocessors.py#L54)

```
def build_block_parser(md, **kwargs):
    """ Build the default block parser used by Markdown. """
    parser = BlockParser(md)
               :
    parser.blockprocessors.register(ParagraphProcessor(parser), 'paragraph', 10)
    return parser
```

つまり、parser を入れ替える事が可能で、具体的には以下の様にします。

```
import markdown, sys
from markdown.extensions.toc import TocExtension
from markdown.util import etree
from os import path

class _ParagraphProcessor(markdown.blockprocessors.BlockProcessor):
    """ Process Paragraph blocks. """

    def test(self, parent, block):
        return True

    def run(self, parent, blocks):
        block = blocks.pop(0)
        if block.strip():
            if self.parser.state.isstate('list'):
                sibling = self.lastChild(parent)
                if sibling is not None:
                    # Insetrt after sibling.
                    if sibling.tail:
                        sibling.tail = '%s\n%s' % (sibling.tail, block)
                    else:
                        sibling.tail = '\n%s' % block
                else:
                    # Append to parent.text
                    if parent.text:
                        parent.text = '%s\n%s' % (parent.text, block)
                    else:
                        parent.text = block.lstrip()
            else:
                # Create a regular paragraph
                p = etree.SubElement(parent, 'p')
                ## Do not delete the spaces at the beginning of a line
                p.text = block

if __name__=='__main__':

    if len(sys.argv) != 2:
        print("変換するファイルを指定してください。")
        sys.exit()

    input_file = sys.argv[1]
    if not path.exists(input_file) or not path.isfile(input_file):
        print("指定されたファイルが見つかりません。")
        sys.exit()

    with open(input_file, "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
        data = f.read()

    md = markdown.Markdown(extensions=['extra', TocExtension(toc_depth="2-6"), 'tables'])
    ## Remove orignal processor
    md.parser.blockprocessors.deregister('paragraph')
    ## Register new processor
    md.parser.blockprocessors.register(_ParagraphProcessor(md.parser), 'paragraph', 10)

    print(md.convert(data))
```

Comment: なるほど。教えていただいたコードで目的の出力を得られました。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 2):

Markdownでは行頭の空白が無視されるので、代わりに `&nbsp;` を入力しておくのはどうですか？

Answer (score 1):

Markdown で行頭のスペースが無くなるのは Markdown の想定挙動です（全角スペースでも除去すべきかは議論が分かれるところですが、たとえば CommonMark は除去します）。また仮にスペースが削除されなかったとしても HTML としてレンダリングされる際に意味が無くなってしまいます。

もしこれが段落始めの字下げなのであれば、スペースで字下げするのではなく CSS の `text-indent` でスタイルを後から付けて字下げするのは如何でしょうか。